# How to make requests to the Sync Adapter run in the order of a call after connecting to the network

Tags: java, android, android-syncadapter

I use sync adapter to sync local database with server database. Request is called when device`s data changes to save changes on the server. It can be done when device has no network connectivity. After connecting all requests are performed in random order, which may cause an error on the dependent data. How can i make Sync Adapter perform requests in order of the call?

Here is my Sync Adapter

```java
public class SyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
    public SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
    }

    public SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize, boolean allowParallelSyncs) {
        super(context, autoInitialize, allowParallelSyncs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
        String table = extras.getString("table");
        String option = extras.getString("option");
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String url = "http://192.168.1.136:8082/save";

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<>(2);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("table", table));
        switch (option) {
            case "SAVE":
                String data = extras.getString("data");
                httpPost = new HttpPost(url + "/insert");
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", data));
                Log.d("SAVE", table + " " + data);
                break;
            case "DELETE":
                Long id = extras.getLong("id");
                httpPost = new HttpPost(url + "/delete");
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id.toString()));
                Log.d("DELETE", table + " " + id);
                break;
        }
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // writing error to Log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here -> syncadapter.xml

```xml
<sync-adapter android:contentAuthority="com.example.alexander.sportdiary.Sync.provider" 
android:accountType="com.example.alexander.sportdiary.Sync"
android:userVisible="false"
android:supportsUploading="false" 
android:allowParallelSyncs="false" 
android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"/>
```

I use simple stub provider, stub authenticator and service from documentation.

I use room database. In places of insert/update/delete I call request to the Sync Adapter with changes in json.

Here are methods to make request

```java
public static void syncSave(String data, String table) {
        Bundle settingsBundle = new Bundle();
        settingsBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
        //settingsBundle.putBoolean("sync_priority", true);
        settingsBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
        settingsBundle.putString("data", data);
        settingsBundle.putString("table", table);
        settingsBundle.putString("option", SAVE.toString());
        ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1);
        ContentResolver.requestSync(account, AUTHORITY, settingsBundle);
    }

    public static void syncDelete(Long id, String table) {
        Bundle settingsBundle = new Bundle();
        settingsBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
        //settingsBundle.putBoolean("sync_priority", true);
        settingsBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
        settingsBundle.putLong("id", id);
        settingsBundle.putString("table", table);
        settingsBundle.putString("option", DELETE.toString());
        ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1);
        ContentResolver.requestSync(account, AUTHORITY, settingsBundle);
    }
```

And example of call it

```java
long trainingId = sportDataBase.trainingDao().insert(training);
training.setId(trainingId);
save(training);

private void save(Training training) {
        AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
                    try {
                        MainActivity.syncSave(
                                MainActivity.getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(
                                        MainActivity.getConverter().convertEntityToDto(training)
                                ), Table.TRAINING
                        );
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

**UPD**:
I ve decided to use WorkManager instead of sync adapter. It satisfies my requirements: perform only while network, run requests even if app is off, run requests in the order of the call by enqueUnique with append strategy.
But it is still not answer on the question.

Comment: I would advice to include some code that you have tried into your question. It will increase the chances to get an answer and reduce the chances to getting it flagged and removed.